# No Activity found to handle Intent, cant find solution android application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to make a simple program that when it runs displays a button, and when the user clicks the button, they are taken to a webpage. However, I keep getting a "No Activity found to handle Intent" error. This is what is in my manifest file currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="school.project.application"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="school.project.application.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity   
        android:name=".AppPreferenceActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">  
        <intent-filter> 
             <action android:name="android.Intent.ACTION_VIEW" />  

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
        </intent-filter>   
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is the code that I am using to launch the webpage when the button is clicked:
    package school.project.application;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private final String TAG = "sendButton";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupsendMessage();



}


private void setupsendMessage() {
// do something when the button is pressed
//
Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(TAG, "You Clicked a button");
        goToUrl("htpp://stackoverflow.com/");


        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void goToSo (View view){
    goToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");

}
private void goToUrl(String url){
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}
```

}

I was wondering if anyone could take sometime to help me correct this problem?
Thank you guys very much.

EDIT:
Here is the stacktrace:

```
11-20 20:38:22.845: I/sendButton(3212): You Clicked a button
11-20 20:38:22.845: W/dalvikvm(3212): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001f560)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at school.project.application.MainActivity.goToUrl(MainActivity.java:64)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at school.project.application.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:61)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at school.project.application.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9081)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3696)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
11-20 20:38:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post a stacktrace please.

Comment: Added the stacktrace.

Comment: Do you get the error after or before pressing the button? Oh nevermind. I just say the log. Is this a Device or an Emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a spelling mistake in your URL:

goToUrl("htpp://stackoverflow.com/");

should be:

goToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");

Comment: LOL, nice spot. I Looked at the URL 3 times.

Comment: Wow, I seem to be very careless tonight. Thank you.